# dpkg is messed up, returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am getting an error when trying to use dpkg in any way. see terminal data:

```
/Downloads$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up lightdm-login-chromiumos (1.0) ...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    40  100    40    0     0    292      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   291
Downloading: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Linux_ChromiumOS/84b76aa34b7ee89ea7b44af59239f6729aa53ab5/chrome-linux.zip
ZIP: /tmp/file9DgGEV.zip
Warning: Illegal date format for -z, --timecond (and not a file name). 
Warning: Disabling time condition. See curl_getdate(3) for valid date syntax.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127  100   127    0     0   1055      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1058
Archive:  /tmp/file9DgGEV.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/file9DgGEV.zip or
        /tmp/file9DgGEV.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/file9DgGEV.zip.ZIP, period.
dpkg: error processing package lightdm-login-chromiumos (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm-login-chromiumos
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here is the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up lightdm-login-chromiumos (1.0) ... 
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current 
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
100 40 100 40 0 0 163 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 163 
Downloading: commondatastorage.googleapis.… 
ZIP: /tmp/fileTPoMun.zip 
Warning: Illegal date format for -z, --timecond (and not a file name). 
Warning: Disabling time condition. See curl_getdate(3) for valid date syntax. 
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current 
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
100 127 100 127 0 0 481 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 482 
Archive: /tmp/fileTPoMun.zip 
End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not 
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the 
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on 
the last disk(s) of this archive. 
unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/fileTPoMun.zip or 
/tmp/fileTPoMun.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/fileTPoMun.zip.ZIP, period. 
dpkg: error processing package lightdm-login-chromiumos (--configure): 
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
lightdm-login-chromiumos
```

Comment: what's the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem was with the external data. The package you installed `lightdm-login-chromiumos` needs external data which seemed to be either corrupted or in wrong format for `unzip` to handle. Anyway, since you cleared (in the chat) that they just want to abort the whole thing, You just need to tell `dpkg` that the package is to be removed.

Just do this in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -r lightdm-login-chromiumos
```